# Gradient Flows, Explicit Form for Regularised Wasserstein Metric.

Tags: entropy, regularization, gradient-flows, optimal-transport

Since this [seminal paper](https://www-dimat.unipv.it/savare/Ravello2010/JKO.pdf) the technique of gradient flows in the Wasserstein space has been widely adopted as a method in approximating solutions to a variety of PDEs (from Fokker-Planck to the porus-medium).

In short, the solution to a PDE is approximated by the interpolation of the following "JKO scheme": given $\rho^0$ we find
\begin{equation}
\rho^{n}_{\tau}=\text{argmin}_{\rho\in \mathcal{P}^r_2(\mathbb{R}^d)} \Big\{
\frac{1}{2\tau}W^2_2(\rho^{n-1}_{\tau},\rho)+F(\rho) \Big\}
\end{equation}
as $\tau \to 0$. Here, $W_2$ is the Wasserstein metric,  $\mathcal{P}^r_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is space of densities on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with finite second moments, and $F$ is some energy function.

It can be desirable to regularise the entropy, i.e. replace $W_2$ by $W_{2,\epsilon}$, where
$$
W_{2,\epsilon}(\mu,\nu)=\inf_{\pi}\Big( \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}|x-y|^2d\pi +\epsilon\,\int \pi \log \pi \Big)^{1/2}.
$$

> My question is: does anyone have any examples where $\rho^n_{\tau}$ has been explicitly calculated, i.e given a $\rho^0$ and a fixed $\tau$ has anyone calculated an explicit form of the sequence of minimisers $\rho^n_\tau$?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is equivalent to asking for examples of closed form solutions of optimal transport problems. One typical example where these exist are gaussian distributions.
See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2639621/closed-forms-solutions-to-optimal-transport-wasserstein-distance).

Comment: Kind of, but its like two optimal problems. Since you need to get the optimal density for the next step in the scheme and then identify the plan between it and the previous one.

Comment: Ah, I see. We're looking for the wasserstein barycenter between $\rho_\tau^{n-1}$ and arg$\min F(\rho)$, where $\tau$ acts as a weight for the interpolation.
If this is the case, then it depends if arg$\min F(\rho)$ has a closed form solution. (I don't have experience with energy functions, but in the paper you linked it looks similar to entropically regularized OT to me.)

Comment: Not really, barycenter means we would be taking a sum of Wassersteins. We are just searching for a minimiser for each step of the JKO scheme (proving the minimiser is indeed the minimiser requires the calculation of the wasserstein term - hence need access to the optimal plan.)

Comment: A kind of trivial example would be the energy $E(\rho)= \int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2 \mathrm{d}\rho$. If you start with $\rho_0$ as the Dirac at $0$, then your sequence of solutions to the discrete variational scheme you have described is exactly the Dirac at $0$.