# Closed form of Wasserstein distance in one dimension

Tags: probability, optimal-transport

On page 8 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.05500.pdf), it says that there is a closed form of 1-Wasserstein distance on $\mathbb{R}$: for any r.v.s $X,Y$ with CDF $F_X,F_Y$, we have

$$W_1(X,Y)=\int|F_X(t)-F_Y(t)|dt$$

Why is this true? I have no idea how to get this closed-form representation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this topic, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2639621/798206) _seems_ to have what you're looking for? (I am referring to develarist's comment there.)

Comment: @cluelessmathematician: those are articles citing a relevant result but I didn't find a proof.

Comment: Bummer ☹️ looked a little more and I found [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.04945.pdf) but its reference was the paper you referenced in your question!!  This is totally out of my areas of expertise, so I am afraid I can't be of much more help. (Perhaps send the authors an email asking for a reference with the proof? Couldn't hurt, and in my experience professors are pretty open to such questions.)

Comment: See e.g. Santambrogio's book 'Optimal transport for Applied Mathematicians'.